# Gradle Task in Android Studio is unknown property

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-task

I am moving an old project which runs in it's original project. But, it's gradle has been giving me issues in a new project. The issue is that my gradle task is not recognized by the preBuild call.

I have tried turning them into references with 'copyAppFiles' or directly naming them without single quotes.

```
Build file 'C:\Users\ZBC\AndroidStudioProjects\MyYapApp\app\build.gradle' line: 88

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'copyAppFiles' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    ...
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'copyAppFiles' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
...
at build_9ohkvz8w7llkrdjeut3507o3h.run(C:\Users\ZBC\AndroidStudioProjects\MyYapApp\app\build.gradle:88)
```

My Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.squareup.sqldelight'
}

android {

    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        applicationId setPropertyValue('applicationId', 'com.flicast.jw')
        targetSdkVersion setPropertyValue('targetSdkVersion', 29)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {...
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            resValue "bool", "DEBUG", "true"
        }
    }

    //list flavorDimensions in override priority order
    flavorDimensions 'platform', 'theme'

//assign each productFlavor a corresponding flavorDimension
productFlavors {
    mobile {
        dimension 'platform'
        minSdkVersion setPropertyValue('mobileMinSdkVersion', 22)
    }
    light {
        dimension 'theme'
    }
    dark {
        dimension 'theme'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api project(':xyzacore-android')
    api project(':app-bridge')
}

task applyAppFiles {
    if (!fileTree('../../app-config/src').isEmpty()) {
        //copy app-config files to jw-app/src
        task copyAppFiles(type: Copy) {              //<-------------
            from ("../../app-config/src") {
                //exclude ""
            }
            into "src"
        }
    }
}

def setPropertyValue(parameterName, defaultValue) {
    if (rootProject.ext[parameterName]) {
        return rootProject.ext[parameterName]
    } else {
        return defaultValue
    }
}

preBuild.dependsOn(copyAppFiles) //<----------------
preBuild.dependsOn(applyAppFiles)
```

Top level gradle settings include

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath "com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:1.2.1"
```

Project structure settings are

```
Gradle Plugin Version 3.6.1
Gradle Version 6.3
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Why do you need a `task` inside `task`?

Comment: @Jay I need to check if the files that I am copying are already available or not, then perform copy.

Comment: please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it's necessary to register `copyAppFiles` inside `applyAppFiles` task.
The [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) documentation states:

> Each task belongs to a Project. Each task has a name, which can be used to refer to the task within its **owning project**, and a fully qualified path, which is unique across all tasks in all projects.

Here, you are encapsulating `copyAppFiles` task *inside* `applyAppFiles` task which is semantically *incorrect*.

You could simply register your copy task as below:

```
task copyAppFiles(type: Copy) {
if (!fileTree('../../app-config/src').isEmpty()) {
    //copy app-config files to jw-app/src
    // <-------------
        from ("../../app-config/src") {
            //exclude ""
        }
        into "src"
    }
}
```

And then call it as dependent to `preBuild` as:

```
preBuild.dependsOn(copyAppFiles)
```

I also think you do not need to check whether the `app-config/src` filetree is empty or not. If it's empty nothing would be copied. Unless, of course, you have a special use-case for this to be checked.